# java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I have few insert and update operations in my application. Everything is **running fine in Tomcat server**. But while deploying in Oracle Weblogic server I'm getting the below exception
**java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on**
In my executUpdate method, I have set **DatabaseConnection.setAutoCommit to false at the  beginning**

```
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false, id);
```

After the PreparedStatement's executeUpdate, if the returned integer is > 0 I'm again setting the setAutoCommit to true something like below:

```
         dbConnection.setIsolationLevel(2,id);
         count = PreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        
         if (cnt > 0)
            dbConn.setAutoCommit(true,id);
```

After all the operations in **finally block**, we check for **DatabaseConnection is null or not and then close it** as something like below:

```
if(dbConnection!=null)
        {
            dbConnection.close(tranid);
            dbConnection= null;
        }
```

The close method we have mocked something like below within a try catch and a message within this catch block's is getting printed :

```
if(connection!=null)
        {
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
        }
```

Someone please help me out with this as a proper commit should occur in realtime as I tried setting AutoCommit to false in the below part and it worked without the SQLException.

```
if (count > 0)
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false,id);
```

My worry is, this is not the solution I'm looking for as this causes problem in realtime

Comment: Why are you change auto commit back to true if you updated rows, rather than just committing at that point? It's too late to affect the statement you just ran, surely, and seems like an odd thing to do anyway?

Comment: I have reused the same code which they have already used in prod appln. I'm re- using the same. I'm alone getting this exception. It's not even coming in their prod code

Comment: It's still odd. I'm surprised that works as you have it; presumably Tomcat has a different JDBC driver, and either ignores it or it has no effect, and it's the close commit that actually matters usually. What is the intention when you set auto commit on at that point - to commit the just-updated rows? Why not just commit?